# XAMPP Error - InnoDB: Operating system error number 3 in a file operation

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, mariadb, xampp

Generally server works fine without any issues. But recently after opening my XAMPP and got this on morning

```
2022-12-10  9:55:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions 
2022-12-10  9:55:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes 
2022-12-10  9:55:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11 2022-12-10  9:55:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1 
2022-12-10  9:55:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions 
2022-12-10  9:55:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M 
2022-12-10  9:55:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool 
2022-12-10  9:55:29 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 3 in a file operation. 
2022-12-10  9:55:29 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified. 
2022-12-10  9:55:29 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them. 
2022-12-10  9:55:29 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\nbc_db2022@002e1\ja_usermeta.ibd' OS error: 203 
2022-12-10  9:55:29 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation. 
2022-12-10  9:55:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/ 
2022-12-10  9:55:29 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``nbc_db2022.1`.`ja_usermeta\`\`. 
Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2022-12-10  9:55:29 0 [Warning\] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `nbc_db2022.1`.`ja_usermeta` because it could not be opened.
2022-12-10  9:55:29 0 \[ERROR\] InnoDB: Operating system error number 3 in a file operation.
2022-12-10  9:55:29 0 \[ERROR\] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2022-12-10  9:55:29 0 \[ERROR\] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2022-12-10  9:55:29 0 \[ERROR\] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\\nbc_db2022@002e1\\wp_commentmeta.ibd' OS error: 203
2022-12-10  9:55:29 0 \[ERROR\] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2022-12-10  9:55:29 0 \[Note\] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/%60
\
```

I have already tried switching ports in PHPMyAdmin and MySQL also deleted aria_log files. I'm using Windows 11 Version 22H2

Comment: Did you read the suggested parts of the manual for assistance

Comment: Looks like you may have a corrupt or maybe even a missing ibdata1 file

Comment: Of course you have a backup, right?

Comment: Yes, I cant see the OS Error: 203 :(

Comment: Bt default all INNODB datbases are store inside a single file call `ibdata` kept in the `data` folder under the mysql installation folder. If thats gone or corrupt it can be fatal, and the good news is even if its not fatal its normally a job for an expert to attampt any sort of recovery

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.